# Simba ODBC Driver for Excel Failing to Retrieve Refresh Token for Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have total of 4 PCs which I am trying to connect to Big Query via SIMBA drivers for Excel downloaded from here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/partners/simba-drivers/.

I succeeded with connecting 2 PCs but failing with the other 2. All are trying to connect to the very same project.

The other 2 are already failing at the ODBC driver setup phase - when logging to BQ via "User Authentication" option in order to get the Confirmation Code for the refresh token. The refresh token is simply failing to be generated. I am getting "Failed to retrieve refresh token. Authentication failed or access token was expired or invalid".

The users can login to Big Query and see the tables which we want to download to Excel.

I did quite some research and seems like no one is having the issue.

Any idea what could be wrong? All the PCs are Win10 64bit.

DZ

Comment: Could it be that meanwhile a request has been made in background, could you please try with different users?

Comment: We actually tried 3 users already.

What worked was to generate service account along with p12 key. That seems to be reliable way to go - it's the 2nd "login option" for the driver.

However, I am still curios why user authentication is not working.

DZ

Comment: because it's an interactive proces, and it's designed for different use, service account is the way to go